# Javascript Replace function not working on first instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, if-statement, replace

I am currently trying to make a list, using javascript and jquery that returns a string of keywords as shown here: keyword+keyword+keyword+keyword

I am attempting to do this by adding a class 'active' when a keyword is clicked as shown in the code below, then checking whether it is active, if it is, add it to a list with an additional + sign (except for the first element, limited by the counter), however whenever I click on an item 2 times consecutively, it is successfully added to the list however is not deleted from it, yet the counter is added and subtracted per usual, and the console log reports the class changing.
The code is below;

```
        $("ul.cats li, ul.colours li ").click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass( 'active');
        });

        var taglist = '';
        var tagcounter = 1;

        $("ul.cats li.tag").click(function(){
            var tag = $(this).attr("list-data");

            if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {   

                if (tagcounter <= 0){
                    taglist += '+';
                }
                taglist += tag;
                tagcounter -= 1;
                console.log('Active');

            }  else {

                var tag2 = '+' + tag;
                taglist = taglist.replace(tag2," ");
                tagcounter += 1;
                console.log('inactive');

            }
            console.log(taglist, 'Taglist', tagcounter);

        });
```

From this I believe I should get a list of keyword1+keyword2+keyword3 however whenever an item is clicked twice in succession, (keyword1 is rendered active and inactive consecutively) the keyword is not deleted yet the counter is incremented and the class is rendered inactive.
Using an example keyword of 'light', this is what is returned by the console;

```
[Log] Active 
[Log] Light Taglist 0 
[Log] inactive 
[Log] Light Taglist 1 (wordpress, line 237)
```

This shows that the class checks and if statement is functioning properly yet the replace function is not.
Please can someone provide a solution to this, I will be eternally grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the check of `tagcounter <= 0`.
When you are checking that for the first time, `tagcounter` is still 1. You decrement it later. Hence the "+" never gets appended. Hence when you are trying to remove "+Light" it doesn't work because the "+" is not there in the taglist.

Move the decrement code `tagcounter -=1` above the tagcounter check.

```
            tagcounter -= 1;
            if (tagcounter <= 0){
                taglist += '+';
            }
            taglist += tag;
```

It works fine. Here is a working demo http://jsfiddle.net/gqgL3dgk/

This would append a "+" in the beginning of your taglist. You can get rid of that extra "+" sign by using substring method.
`taglist = taglist.substring(1); //includes all characters except the 0th`

**Recommendation**
Since you have to maintain a list, use a data structure that is more suited for a list (i.e. an Array) and convert that to a  "+" separated string when you need it.
You can keep pushing/pulling tags from the array and convert it to a "+" separated string using the join() method.

Working fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/gqgL3dgk/1/

This will remove your dependency on tagcounter (because the array length can get you that). And adding and removing elements is super simple.

Comment: Thats the point though, I don't want the first keyword to have a + in front of it, how would I get around this?

Comment: Remove the first character from taglist. By taglist = taglist.substring(1);

Comment: I have made an edit. Showing the right way to solve the problem. Please look at that as well

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of `.replace()` needs to be a regular expression. You can generate it from a string by using `new RegExp()`:

```
taglist = taglist.replace(new RegExp(tag2)," ");
```

**Edit:** Ooops - a string *is* valid as a first agrument. It is not treated like a regular expression, but in this example it doesn't need to be.